# Geting the start and end index of the first consecutive sequence of the same character in a python String

Tags: python, string

I want to get the start and finish index of the first consecutive sequence of the same character
string in python

```
'aaabca' -> (0, 2)

'helllooo' ->  (2, 4)

'hellooo' -> (2,3)

'abcd' -> (-1, -1)
```

is there a super clean way to accomplish that?

Comment: What do you mean by "super clean"? Why is this important?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `regex` that find the repetition of a char (`(\w)\1+`), then get the position of the match (using `m.start()` and `m.end()`)

```
values = ['aaabca', 'helllooo', 'hellooo', 'abcd']

for value in values:
    m = re.search(r'(\w)\1+', value)
    if m:
        print(f'{value:10s}{str((m.start(), m.end() - 1)):10s}{m.group(0)}')
    else:
        print(f'{value:10s}{str((-1, -1)):10s}')
```

Giving

```
aaabca    (0, 2)    aaa
helllooo  (2, 4)    lll
hellooo   (2, 3)    ll
abcd      (-1, -1)
```

---

#### Note

To change the type of char to search a repetition on, replace the `\w`

- `(\d)\1+` repetition of a digit
- `(.)\1+` repetition of any char
- `([a-z])\1+` repetition of a lower case
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it

```
x = "helllooo"

count = 0
start = -1
end = -1
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    if x[i] == x[i+1]:
        if count == 0:
            start = i
        count += 1
        end = start + count
    else:
        if count > 0:
            break
        count = 0

print(start, end)
```

Answer (score 0):

My first answer on stackoverflow. I hope you can give me rep :)
Totally works have a nice day

```
word_list=['aaabca','helllooo','hellooo','abcd']

def find(word):
    first_char=[]
    index_list=[]

    for n,i in enumerate(word):
         
        if n+1<len(word):
            
            if i==word[n+1]:
                first_char.append(i)
                
                while first_char[0]==i:
                    
                    index_list.append(n)
                    index_list.append(n+1)
                    break
    try:
        print(index_list[0],index_list[-1])
    except:
        print(-1,-1)
    
for word in word_list:
    find(word)
```